그러게 and 그래 exclamation origin
I am curious about the grammar behind these words when used as exclamation to support or agree with the words of the other party.
More concretely, I am unsure whether these words come from the verb 그러다 (to say so) or 그렇다 (to be so) and in the word 그러게 I am not sure if -게 is the adverbial suffix or it has a different role. Originally, I just thought they all more or less conveyed the meaning of "yeah it is like that" (via 그렇다) or variations of it to show agreement, but I've seen people mention other origins related to 그러다 and expressions like 그러게 말이야 (I'll say!) and now I am confused.

It can be difficult to grasp their exact meanings partly because they have quite a few related but slightly different usages.
As you mentioned, 그래 can mean either 그렇다 or 그러다.  그렇다 is a contraction of 그러하다, and adjective, and 그러다 of 그리하다 and 그렇게 하다, both of which are verbs.  So 그래 can be used as both verb and adjective. The context determines which one to use.
As for the meanings:

그래 (그러해) = I agree = Yes, that's right.  This is essentially a statement  of agreement, but if said with high enthusiasm, it can be an exclamation.
그래 (그리해 / 그렇게 해) = Ok, go ahead and do so. This is more of an instruction or giving permission.

In everyday situations, we use 그래 somewhat vaguely without much thought to their grammatical role, but when you use different sentence endings, they take on different forms.  For example, a supervisor at a workplace might say 그러세요 (= 그렇게 하세요) instructing their staff member.  It is because an honorific suffix 시 is added (the derivation is 그러시어요 -> 그러셔요 -> 그러세요) of the instructional 그래 for politeness whereas the agreement 그래 doesn't need it (honorific forms are expected when the subject of the verb is the other person, excepting children).  So we have 그러세요 vs 그래요, and if you get more formal, you'll use 그러십시오/그렇게 하십시오 vs 그렇습니다. So you'll need good understanding of sentence ending forms to have full grasp of 그래 and the related phrases.
그러게 is similar in meaning to 그래 as an agreement, but it is not a sentential form but a shortening of 그러게 말이야.
(*Note: There is also 그러게 (= 그리하게 / 그렇게 하게) as a sentence ending form, but this -게 ending form is not directly related to what we're talking about.  It is also falling out of use now)
그러게 (말이야) may be thought of as a special idiom rather than another variation of 그래.  Compared to 그래, it goes further as if saying "Yeah, that's exactly what I thought". 그러게나 is another variant, but we don't say그렇게(나).  Using -게 (which usually means intent or effect) this way seems to exist only in these idiomatic phrases.
Hope it clarifies some of your confusions.  Feel free to ask any other question you might have.
